# working of static in following code

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    static int x = 11;
    private int y = 33;
    public void method(int x) {
        Test t = new Test();
        this.x = 22;
        y = 44;
        System.out.println(Test.x);
        System.out.println(t.x);
        System.out.println(t.y);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.method(5);
    }
}
```

Here the code is ok and it gives output like: `22 22 33 44`

but I don 't understand:

1. Why `Test.x` isn't `11` and give output like: `11 22 33 44`
2. Why `t.y` and `y` isn't a 44 and 44 and gives output like:`11 22 44 44`
3. Why `t.method(5)` is not executed in this code?

Answer (score 0):

1) `x` is static, there is only one of them.  So `Test.x` and `this.x` are the same var.

2) `y` is not static, so they *are* separate vars.

3) `method()` *is* executed.  Otherwise you would get no output.

BTW, I think you might be confusing yourself by having two instances of Test, both called `t`.  I would rename one.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a static field and an instance field is that the static field is not instance-dependent.

Look here:

```
static int x = 11;
private int y = 33;
```

The static field `x` will be the same for every instance of `Test` while the field of `y` will be instance specific. That's why you see these results.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand what `static` keyword does, here's a good question to start with: [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Now that you know that `static` makes a variable a member of the Class and not of the instance, you will know that if an instance of class modify a static field of that class, another instance will see the modified value, we can go through your questions:

> 1. Why `Test.x` isn't `11` and give output like: `11 22 33 44`

`Test.x` refers to this variable: `static int x = 11;`, which you're modifying its value to `22` here:

```
this.x = 22;
```

In this case, you have a local variable, which you're receiving as a parameter `int x`. When using `this` keyword, you're accessing the instance of this class and as it's a static variable, there's no instance but you access it.

So, when you call `this.x = 22` is like saying `Test.x = 22`.

> 2. Why `t.y` and `y` isn't a `44` and `44` and gives output like: `11 22 44 44`

It's due to `y` not being static, so it has it's own value. When you call `new Test();`, the variable `t` creates a new instance having a variable called `y` initialized to `33`, because of this:

```
private int y = 33;
```

So, when you call `t.y` it prints the above result because it's a different instance.

When you print `y`, then you're calling the variable `y` which is in use in the program right now (and it's a different instance from the one above), and you changed its value to `44` before printing it.

That's why the first `this.y` prints `33` and `y` prints `44`

> 3. Why `t.method(5)` is not executed in this code?

It's indeed being executed, or you wouldn't see any output at all, but you don't get a `5` because you're never using the local variable in the parameters `int x`. You could try writing

```
System.out.println(x);
```

So you get that value.